# How to tell what request a form submit will/has sent?

Tags: html, google-chrome

In Chrome, I want to see exactly what was (or preferably will be) sent when I submit a simple HTML form. Even if the form uses POST, can I still reproduce the submission by encoding these parameters into an URL?

e.g.

```
<form action="profile.php?userid=123" method="post">
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Yes" name="confirm">
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="No" name="deny">
</form>
```

Comment: why don't you just use Chrome debugger to sniff the HTTP request? (In the network tab of the debugging tools, accessed with F12)

Comment: that's kind of the question, I think! Not familiar with the Chrome tools.

Answer (score 4):

Press Ctrl + Shift + J or Ctrl + Shift + C to open Chrome Developer Tools, and switch to Network tab. It shows exacly what you want.

A screenshot for this:

[image: network tab]

Comment: If you go further in this, you will be able to see the post/get parameters.